# springMVC ,how to delete a link (href)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

```
package net.roseindia.controller;

import net.roseindia.service.ArticleService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class DeleteController {
    @Autowired
      private ArticleService articleService;

      @RequestMapping(value="/delete")
      public String deleteService(@RequestParam("ID") final Integer ids) {
          System.out.println("hello");
          articleService.deleteService(ids);

          return "redirect:/articles";

      }

}
```

may be here~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
<td><a href="/articles/delete.do?ID=${article.articleId}">delete</a></td>
```

This problem just sticked me a lot.I think it might be the problem of href.Controller could not grasp the link of href

(second try)But It seems it also does not work like this

```
import net.roseindia.service.ArticleService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class DeleteController {
    @Autowired
      private ArticleService articleService;

      @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{ID}")
      public String deleteService(@PathVariable("ID") final Integer ids) {
          System.out.println("hello");
          articleService.deleteService(ids);

          return "redirect:/articles";

      }

}

    td><a href="/articles/delete/${article.articleId}.html">delete</a></td>
```

this is my web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>

<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Promble is

HTTP Status 404 - /articles/delete/2.html

---

type Status report

message /articles/delete/2.html

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: <a href="/articles/delete/${article.articleId}.html">delete</a>-----this does not work for being grasped by Controller

Comment: it looks ok, are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Reason for Http 404 error is no mapping found for your http request. Seems from your configurations that your controller and request mapping is not getting configured.

you need to define your **dispatcher** with some context configuration as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and then in `servlet-context.xml`, you need to define **component-scan** as follows to scan your annotation driven controllers:

```
<annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.roseindia.controller" />
```